# Atualizar trecho de JSP via Servlet

Tags: java, html, ajax, jsp, servlet

tenho o seguinte caso:

Tenho um arquivo index.jsp, que tem a estrutura abaixo:

```
<jsp:include page="templates/header.jspf"/>
<div id="view">
<jsp:include page="home.jspf"/>
</div>
<jsp:include page="templates/footer.jspf"/>
```

Para a navegação eu chamo as páginas via ajax, e altero o conteúdo da div de id="view", através do JS abaixo:

```
function abrirPag(valor){

    var url = valor;

    xmlRequest.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = mudancaEstado;
    xmlRequest.send(null);
    return url;
}

function mudancaEstado(){
    if (xmlRequest.readyState == 4){
        document.getElementById("view").innerHTML = xmlRequest.responseText;
    }
}
```

Porém estou com um problema. Tenho um formulário de login, que aceita login de clientes e administradores. Após o login, eu gostaria que o sistema validasse o tipo de usuário e recarregasse esse index.jsp incluindo o header correspondente (é um header para usuário não logado, outro para clientes e outro para administradores). Não estou conseguindo fazer isso via servlet.

Tentei usar o RequestDispatcher para isso, mas não deu certo.

Também tentei chamar a função JS pra recarregar a página, porém ela roda independente do fluxo do Servlet e não consigo saber se o usuário que tentou logar realmente existe, nem se ele é admin ou cliente.

Alguém sabe como eu poderia resolver isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução seria criar as 3 estruturas do header na página e deixa-las invisível. Você as torna visível de acordo com o retorno vindo da Servlet. Este retorno pode ser um json simples.

Exemplo:

```
<div class="invisible" id="adm">
<!-- aqui o código para montar o header de adm -->
</div>
<div class="invisible" id="client">
<!-- aqui o código para montar o header de adm -->
</div>
<div class="invisible" id="default">
<!-- aqui o código para montar o header de adm -->
</div>
```

Então você faz uma requisição ajax para a Servlet:

```
$.post("your-domain.com/login", {username: "admin", password: "123admin"}).done(function(retorno){
       var json = JSON.parse(retorno);
       if(json.isAdmin){
          $("#adm").removeClass("invisible");
       } else if(json.isClient) {
          $("#client").removeClass("invisible");
       }
       //continua a logica para não logado também
});
```

Por fim, na servlet, você retorna um json caso o login foi de acordo com o esperado (administrador, cliente, não logado)

```
//Logica de negócio, verifica no banco, bla bla bla
//...
Resultado resultado = new Resultado();
resultado.setIsAdmin(true);
resultado.setIsCliente(false);
resultado.setNaoLogado(false);
Gson gson = new Gson();

response.setContentType("text/html");
response.getWriter().write(gson.toJson(resultado));
```

Esta é apenas uma entre diversas soluções no qual você pode optar.

Para criar o JSON a partir de uma classe, utilizei a lib do Google chamada Gson.
Utilizei JQuery também para enviar uma requisição post para a servlet.

Comment: Interessante esta abordagem. Vou testar aqui e retorno confirmando se consegui ou não. Muito obrigado!